# How to increase horizontal subdivisions without increasing vertical

Tags: edit-mode

I'm using this grid of strips as the rubber flaps you see on airport luggage scanners. It currently has a cloth simulation applied to it.

[image]

I was wondering how I could increase the vertical resolution of the flaps so that it doesn't looks so segmented. Subdivision Surface modifier and shade smooth don't do the trick, and I'd like to do it without increasing the vertical divisions so as to cut down vertices.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the bevel modifier to work and I don't know if I'm smart enough to try Robin's suggestion but I did get it to work by selecting the existing horizontal sections, deleting them, and re-adding them with shift-R

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a bevel modifier:

Select the horizontal edge loops and set them a bevel weight.

And add a bevel modifier with a limit method based on the weights.

[image]

Edit: in your case, you may want to select the edges by selecting one loop and select similar length or direction.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too much for this question, but, for tweakability, *Array* and *Solidify* modifiers play well with *Cloth*. You can set up two curve-lines for X and Z, and array a simple plane to fit both. (X with a relative offset).

Your 'Pin' vertex-group can be controlled by the X line and *Vertex Weight Proximity*, while you Z-scale the plane to control the number of divisions:

[image]

*Solidify* can be assigned before or after *Cloth*, for subtly different effects.

[image]

[image]